# SQL Server logs "blob data", viewable with journalctl

Tags: sql-server, linux, errors, logs

What does it mean when I run `journalctl -u mssql-server.service` and it says `B blob data`,

```
Sep 06 17:34:44 x230 systemd[1]: Stopping Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine...
Sep 06 17:34:44 x230 sqlservr[22239]: [200B blob data]
Sep 06 17:34:44 x230 sqlservr[22239]: [190B blob data]
Sep 06 17:34:51 x230 sqlservr[22239]: [73B blob data]
Sep 06 17:34:51 x230 sqlservr[22239]: [146B blob data]
Sep 06 17:39:51 x230 sqlservr[22239]: [73B blob data]
Sep 06 17:39:51 x230 sqlservr[22239]: [146B blob data]
```

I'm not running DDL commands either, nor inserting or updating blob data. But it is possible something like `mssql-cli` is doing that in the background.

Answer (score 6):

This happens when there are unprintable characters in the output.

It seems sqlservr is outputting `\r` (or `^M`) (line feed) characters.

You can view the raw data using: `journalctl -u mssql-server.service --all`

From what I can see, this appears to be the same content as `/var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog`, so that might be an easier way to view logs.

Comment: Also use `-f` to follow and scroll automatically.